# Where can I view attachments that I've uploaded to salesforce using a REST api?

Tags: attachment, files, simple-salesforce

```java
response = requests.post('https://%s.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Attachment/' % instance,
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % sessionId },
    data = json.dumps({
        'ParentId': '*******',
        'Name': 'rest_test.txt',
        'body': body
    })
)
```

This is the code I'm using to upload it. I get a successful response,however, the attachment isn't below the Account. I'm giving the id of the account to the ParentId key as a value.

Comment: Most likely you are looking at the wrong Related List. Attached files in Lightning are `ContentDocument`/`ContentVersion`, not `Attachment`. You can run SOQL queries to confirm that your Attachment is bring created.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to salesforce setup
Then to Object Manager -> (the object you want the attachment to be uploaded to) so for me I chose contact
Then to page layouts -> (Object i.e contact) layouts
finally drag notes & attachments